# Pivot grid control for VB6. Does it exist?

Tags: vb6, grid, pivot-table, ocx

I am looking for an OCX control that will work with VB6 and is capable of producing a grid like the one below.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: @tommieb75 No, MSFlexGrid doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After surveying the 3rd party market, I could not find a single ActiveX control that could pivot data in a flexible manner.  Ended up using DevExpress XtraPivotGrid for .NET via Interop.

Answer (score 1):

[ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSFlexGridPro/) still makes a suite of ActiveX controls for VB6.  Their VSFlexGridPro is very flexible (pun intended).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not even come close to what I need.